# How to download an artifact with all its dependencies?

Tags: android, maven, download, repository

i want learn download an artifact with its all dependencies. for example how to download com.android.tools.build/gradle artifact (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/2.3.0) with its all dependencies 
by mvn command in terminal (command prompt) or other any way. at all i just want learn download an artifact with its all dependencies in maven repository and i don't want create an java project. just "download an artifact with its all dependencies."

i downloaded Android Studio and it has Android gradle plugin artifact and its dependencies.

[image]

how to download this artifact with its dependencies **in one folder**???

Comment: One needs to specify what "all dependencies" means: All transitive dependencies? All versions of the transitive dependencies (if log4j appears twice in the dependency tree, do you want to have both?) Plugins specified in the pom.xml? Maybe I can help you narrow down your question when you tell us what your ultimate goal is, i.e. what you want to do with the dependencies.

Comment: *i don't want create an java project* You must not create a Java Project. You only Need a pom.XML with the "start" dependency

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command:

```
mvn -DgroupId=com.android.tools.build -DartifactId=gradle -Dversion=2.3.0 -DremoteRepositories="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" dependency:get
```

It will fetch your dependencies from the informed repository. The JARs will be downloaded into your local Maven Repository.

Docs around `dependency:get` dependency:get can [be found in here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html).

---

Unfortunately I could not find any option for this plugin to specify a output directory for all the artifacts, I have tried the `-DoutputDirectory` option but it does not seem to work for this plugin.

I would suggest then to temporarily change the path of your `localRepository` in your Maven `settings.xml` to a new folder, which will hold the downloaded JARs:

```
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  -->
  <localRepository>DOWNLOADED_JARS_OUTPUT_FOLDER</localRepository>
```

Comment: @YazdanBodaghi Unfortunately I did not find anything related to a output directory or folder option on this plugin, but I have complemented my answer with a workaround for this. Please check

Comment: @YazdanBodaghi you missed the link address

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276515/maven-dependencyget-doutputdirectory-doesnt-work-how-to-download-or-copy-a

Comment: @YazdanBodaghi, the mentioned workaround didn't attend what you are asking on your second question?

Comment: And also I just tested, if you mix my answer with @JF answer you will achieve what you want