# Maven: dependency:get -DoutputDirectory doesn't work. (How to download or copy an artifact with all its dependencies to specific folder?)

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, repository

I try the following way but it doesn't work.

> mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha07 -DoutputDirectory=C:\Users\username\Desktop\MyFolder

Does anyone know another way of achieving my goal?

My goal is to download an artifact with all its dependencies in a folder.

The dpendency:copy-dependencies command only copies jar files, but I want to have an artifact with all its dependencies like the local repository folder structure. for example the photo below shows [an artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/3.4.0-alpha07) with all its dependencies that have been downloaded from the maven repository (I want this).

[image]

I download [this artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/3.4.0-alpha07) with all its dependencies with dependency:get command and then be stored in the local repository and combined with other folders that are in the local repository.

How am I to copy this artifact, along with all its dependencies from the local repository (or maven repository) to another folder.

I don't want to use the dependency:copy-dependencies command because it only copies jar files, but I want files and folders, as they are downloaded with dependency:get command (like the local repository folder structure).

Unfortunately, the following command does not store files and folders in the location I want.

> mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha07 -DoutputDirectory=C:\Users\username\Desktop\MyFolder

Comment: It would be better not to ask similar questions again and again, but to discuss the details in the comments. I still do not understand what you mean by "it only copies jar files". Which other files do you want? pom files? directories?

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of what you mean by copying all dependencies. Which files in which structure do you expect?

Comment: Additionally, I would be interested what you want this for, i.e. what you want to do with this "artifact with all dependencies".

Comment: I agree with @JFMeier, mixing his answer and answer I have provided in the last post will download all the dependencies related to the artifactId. But it seems it is not exactly what you want

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=someDir dependency:get ...
```

?

You can specify any directory as local repository on the command line, so `dependency:get` will copy the results to that directory.

Comment: That's not my answer. Because the files of dependency are downloaded in local repository. But I only want the folders and files associated with the dependencies that I set in the CDM. not more. (I don't want files and files for the dependency:get)

Comment: Edit:Because the files of dependency are downloaded in local repository >>> Because the files of **dependency plugin** are downloaded in local repository

Comment: @JFMeier liked the `maven.repo.local` argument, is there a doc for all arguments available?